# Using ARM assembly language to find two's Complement

Tags: assembly, arm

Write a program in ARM assembly language that will calculate the two's complement of a 32-bit number that is in R2. The result should be in Register R3.

I'm new to ARM coding. I feel like I'm over complicating things, it should be simple. I think I'm getting my location pointer wrong.

```
Loop:   SUB     R0, [R2, R1], #1
    SUB R1, R1, #1
    CBNZ    R0, Cont
    LDRB    [R3,R1], #1
    B   Exit
Cont:   LDRB    [R3,R1], #0
    B   Loop
Exit:   SUB     R0, [R2, R1], #1
    SUB R1, R1, #1
    CBZ R0, One
    LDRB    [R3,R1], #1
    SUB R0, R1, #1
    CBZ R0, Done
    B   Exit 
One:    LDRB    [R3,R1], #0
    SUB R0, R1, #1
    CBZ R0, Done
    B   Exit
Done:   LSL R3
```

Comment: You might be interested in `NEG` or `RSB`. Not sure why you are even accessing memory? It's as simple as `NEG R2, R2`. Done.

Comment: Well, since "result should be in register R3" you obviously want `NEG R3, R2`. But that should have been clear.

Comment: I didn't realise there was a cbz instruction in ARM32.

Comment: They (CBNZ, CBZ) appear to be thumb only and were added in ARMv6T2.  So that means cortex-m0 and the armv7-m and armv7-ar.   And interestingly are not thumb2 extensions despite being added with the introduction of thumb2 extensions.

Comment: and a number of these other instructions are arm only.  So thanks for pointing that out this code doesnt work as is because it mixes arm only instructions and thumb only instructions...gotta love the unified syntax...